# SuiteScript2.0 calling a Suitelet From User Event Not Working

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

**What Do I Want To Happen**

I want to be able to call a Suitelet from a User Event passing in a record id.

**What Currently Happens**

Either a "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION" error is thrown or no error is thrown but the suitelet is not called.

**The Details**

Hey all, I'm trying to call a suitelet from a User Event. We have a record getting created with some data, upon creating that record in the user event I want to create a Customer and Sales Order. I also need the User Events of those records to fire off. I know a user event cannot trigger another user event so I have written a suitelet to call which will do the processing. I am trying to call the suitelet with the following code.

```
var scheme = 'https://';
var host = url.resolveDomain({
    hostType: url.HostType.APPLICATION
});
var suitletURL = url.resolveScript({
    scriptId : 'customscript_pws_sl_data',
    deploymentId : 'customdeploy_pws_sl_data'
});
var parameters = {
    dataid : scriptContext.newRecord.id,
};
log.debug("URL", scheme + host + suitletURL);
var response = https.post({
    url  : scheme + host + suitletURL + "&dataid=" + scriptContext.newRecord.id,
    body : parameters
});
```

Using this code, no errors are thrown, but the Suitelet is also not triggered. I know this because as soon as my suitelet triggers I log "Running"

```
log.debug("Running");
var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
var script = runtime.getCurrentScript();

// Get parameters
var params = context.request.parameters;
log.debug("Context", JSON.stringify(context.request));
log.debug("Params", JSON.stringify(params));
```

Now I am logging the URL that the User Event is using and if I copy and paste that into the browser, the suitelet runs. So I know the URL is correct.

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

I have tried adding the

```
returnExternalUrl: true
```

parameter of the https call. Using this **DOES** call the Suitelet however I can an error stating

```
"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION","message":"Permission Violation: You need the 'Lists -> Items' permission to access this page. Please contact your account administrator.","stack":["createError(N/error)","getOrderLines(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_lib_ecommerce.js:972)","processData(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_lib_ecommerce.js:109)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_sl_ecommdata.js:40)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION","details":"Permission Violation: You need the 'Lists -> Items' permission to access this page. Please contact your account administrator.","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["createError(N/error)","getOrderLines(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_lib_ecommerce.js:972)","processData(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_lib_ecommerce.js:109)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/PWS Additional Modules/Additional Modules/Ecommerce Data/pws_sl_ecommdata.js:40)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

The Suite Deployment is set to "Available Without Login : true" and "All Roles : true"

**Update**

```
I am getting You must login before accessing this page.
```

I am logged in and calling it from a UserEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting both the User Event and Suitelet to run in Administrator mode and using the "returnExternalUrl: true" setting solved this problem :)

```
var suitletURL = url.resolveScript({
    scriptId          : 'customscript_pws_sl_data',
    deploymentId      : 'customdeploy_pws_sl_data',
    returnExternalUrl : true
});
```

Comment: Can you specify what is "setting both user event and suitelet to run in administrator mode" ? How do you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I already running both script as administrator, I log the current user and i get this. It is not the administrator role

```json
{
   id: -4,
   name: "-Sistema-",
   email: "onlineformuser@5273359-sb1.com",
   location: 0,
   department: 0,
   role: 31,
   roleId: "online_form_user",
   roleCenter: "CUSTOMER",
   subsidiary:1
}
```